# vPython doesn't show my 3D object correctly

Tags: python, 3d, vpython, polyhedra

I tried to draw a set of octahedra by vpython, it showed, however, the scene looks don't like a 3D object, it looks just like a colored shadow, whatever how I rotate it. I have no idea how to fix this problem.

```
from vpython import *
from itertools import *
import numpy as np

faces = [[vertex(pos=vec(*v)) for v in np.diag(i)] 
          for i in product(*[(-1,1)]*3)]

octa = compound([triangle(vs=i) for i in faces])
octa.visible=False

centers = [vec(*i) for i in product(*[(-1,0,1)]*3) if sum(i)%2==0]
octa_group = compound([octa.clone(pos=i) for i in centers])

octa_group.color = vec(0.5,0.9,1)
#octa_group.opacity = 0.5

while True:
    rate(30)
```

It shows the scene as follows.
[image]

I expect an effect like this (It seems no problem with built-in 3D objects like box)
[image]

Comment: The only "effect" in the second scene is that there is one colour per face orientation: light for the faces facing us, medium for the faces facing up, and dark for the faces facing to our right. Perhaps you can display your scene with one colour per face orientation as well? One way to characterise the orientation of a face is to calculate a unit-norm normal vector for the face.

Comment: Unrelatedly, using `from something import *` instead of `import something` is not a great habit. If two functions from two modules have the same name, one of them will shadow the other; in any case it becomes hard for someone who reads your code to understand which function comes from where. I suggest using `import vpython; import itertools` or `import vpython as vpy; import itertools as it` or some variant, so that you then write `itertools.product` or `it.product`, just like you did with numpy (`import numpy as np` and not `from numpy import *`)

Comment: Presumably you don't need to compute the surface normal vectors yourself, and can adjust the lightsource so it does the work for you: https://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/light.html

Comment: It looks like you have not specified normals for the triangles, which will lead to the washed-out objects you display.